# locking critical regions with pthread mutex?

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

Suppose I have a multithreaded program with several shared global variables that are used in severeal parts of the threaded function.

My question is: Am I able to declare only one lock and use throughout the program?

I mean... when I lock a block of code, am I only preventing other threads from executing that particular block of code... or am I preventing the execution of all other blocks of code that require the aquisition of the lock?

summary: Do I need to declare a lock for each different critical region?

I hope I made sense... Im still new to these concepts

Comment: "... am I preventing the execution of all other blocks of code that require the aquisition of the lock?" -> yes. when you call `pthread_mutex_lock`, if the mutex is used it will block the thread where `pthread_mutex_lock` is called, and the thread will restart its execution when `pthread_mutex_unlock` is called by the thread which had the mutex.

Answer (score 0):

> or am I preventing the execution of all other blocks of code that require the aquisition of the lock?

Yes, that's it. Whatever code any thread executes, it will block on the mutex until it can be acquired.

Answer (score 0):

Shared resources shall be protected against concurrent access. So you could use one mutex per resource.

In your case a resource is exactly one global variable.

Of course you could protect several resources using the same mutex, but this tends to be in-efficient as code sections might get blocked although they do not need to be.